# Keycloak - Get client scope by name

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'm using the Keycloak Admin Rest API and would like to create a new client scope and get its `id`.

To create the client scope I use this endpoint:

```
http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/master/client-scopes
```

Body

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "display.on.consent.screen": "true",
    "include.in.token.scope": "true"
  },
  "name": "example",
  "protocol": "openid-connect"
}
```

This endpoint doesn't return a result but I need the `ID`.

To get the `ID` I could get all client scopes and find the scope with the matching name however I would have thought there would be a simpler way.

E.g. GET `http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/master/client-scopes` then filter through the results to find a matching name.

Is it possible to get a client scope by name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to get a client scope by name?

Unfortunately, not, which is a pity because the 'name' is unique. If you look at the keycloak [Rest Admin API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/index.html#_client_scopes_resource) you can see the followings `GET` for the client-scopes:

```
GET /{realm}/client-scopes
```

and

```
GET /{realm}/client-scopes/{id}
```

And none of those endpoints accepts as parameters 'name'.

Notwithstanding, as [@csbrogi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8818406/csbrogi) and [@Jan Garaj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3348604/jan-garaj) have pointed out in the comment section, since you:

> (..) create a new client scope and get its id.

You can retrieve the ID of the client-scope that was just created from the header location:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the Keycloak, usually POST methods returns 201 or 200 OK without body as experienced. Thus, you cannot get the ID directly from response. What you can do is; assign a ID while creating scope as below body and you simply will have it.

```
{
  "id": "da5a68f1-058c-481a-bf84-deb95b1f21aa",
  "attributes": {
    "display.on.consent.screen": "true",
    "include.in.token.scope": "true"
  },
  "name": "example",
  "protocol": "openid-connect"
}
```

Comment: I didn't realise this. Another good alternative thank you.